# Issue ArgumentError: Error #1063

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I create timer class in AS3 name `MainTimer.as` and I have `main.as` is use MainTimer class to countdown. When I sent parameters to MainTimer class it error `ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on MainTimer(). Expected 2, got 0.` And when I `trace(startMin, startSec);` in MainTimer show `1 0` . Anybody help.

MainTimer.as

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;

public class MainTimer extends MovieClip {

    private var currentMin: int;
    private var currentSec: int;
    private var oneSecTimer: Timer = new Timer(1000, 1);
    public var timerHasStopped: Boolean = false;

    public function MainTimer(startMin: int, startSec: int) {
        trace(startMin, startSec);

        currentMin = startMin;
        currentSec = startSec;

        minBox.text = String(currentMin);
        secBox.text = String(currentSec);

        if (currentSec < 10) {
            secBox.text = "0" + String(currentSec);
        }

        oneSecTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
        oneSecTimer.start();
        // trace(currentMin, currentSec);
    }

    private function onTimerComplete(event: TimerEvent): void {
        minBox.text = String(currentMin);
        secBox.text = String(currentSec);
        //trace(secBox.text);
        if (currentSec < 10) {
            secBox.text = "0" + String(currentSec);
        }
        currentSec = currentSec - 1;
        if (currentSec <= -1) {
            currentSec = 59;
            currentMin -= 1;
            //trace(minBox.text);
        }
        if (currentMin <= -1) {
            timerHasStopped = true;
            //resetTimer();
        } else {
            oneSecTimer.start();
        }
    }

    public function resetTimer(): void {
        currentMin = 0;
        currentSec = 20;
        minBox.text = String(currentMin);
        secBox.text = String(currentSec);
        if (currentSec < 10) {
            secBox.text = "0" + String(currentSec);
        }
        timerHasStopped = false;
        oneSecTimer.start();
    }

    public function increaseTime(): void {
        currentSec += 20;
    }

}}
```

main.as

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import MainTimer;

public class main extends MovieClip {
    private var startMin: int = 1;
    private var startSec: int = 0;
    private var gameTimer: MainTimer = new MainTimer(startMin, startSec);

    public function main() {
        addChild(gameTimer);
    }

}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you have inserted manually an instance of your `MainTimer` movie clip in the Stage.

So to avoid the `#1063` error, you have to remove that instance or simply define default values in your `MainTimer` class constructor :

```
// ...

public function MainTimer(startMin:int = 1, startSec:int = 0) 
{
    // ...
}

// ...
```

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import MainTimer;

public class main extends MovieClip {
    private var startMin: int = 1;
    private var startSec: int = 0;
    private var gameTimer: MainTimer;

    public function main() {
        gameTimer = new MainTimer(startMin, startSec);
        addChild(gameTimer);
    }}}
```

Try like this it should work :)